# summarize df by Unique values from two different columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

say I have the following df:

| Origin | Lat | Long | Destination | Lat | Long |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | -6.925767 | 52.837445 | B | -6.939444 | 52.836141 |
| A | -6.925767 | 52.837445 | C | -6.717989 | 52.887184 |
| B | -6.939444 | 52.836141 | A | -6.925767 | 52.837445 |
| B | -6.939444 | 52.836141 | C | -6.717989 | 52.887184 |

I need to get the df in the following shape

| Unique Location | Lat | Long |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | -6.925767 | 52.837445 |
| B | -6.939444 | 52.836141 |
| C | -6.717989 | 52.887184 |

is there a quick way to do that using NumPy/pandas? I was trying to split the data into two dfs and then join them together but it seems to be like inefficient way at all.

Answer (score 2):

Use `pd.concat` and `drop_duplicates`:

```
>>> pd.concat([df.iloc[:, :3].rename(columns={'Origin': 'Unique Location'}),
               df.iloc[:, 3:].rename(columns={'Destination': 'Unique Location'})]) \
      .drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)

  Unique Location  Lat  Long
0               A    1     3
1               B    5     3
2               C    7     3
```

Comment: agreed, i think this is the best way, even though OP wanted to avoid a split-join

Comment: @tdy, Hard to do differently, except using `networkx`

Comment: Thanks, Corralien. The only thing that Long values in my original data are also changing and not fixed as I indicated in my example.

Comment: Can you update your post with a real case and the expect result, please?

Comment: I have updated the post now

Comment: @Kimchi. I tested my solution on your new data and it works. What is your problem?

Comment: the script is working and returning all values in Origin and Destination cols within the new Unique Locations col. However, it returns them without dropping duplicated values. Also, most of the Origin lat and lang values are missing.

Comment: Maybe you want to drop duplicates only for column `Unique Location`?